# How to show local axis of objects/gizmo when animating?

Tags: animation, gizmo

During animation gizmo axes isn't being shown. It is only shown when an object is clicked. Is there a way to always keep the gizmo axes shown?

Comment: Not that I know but I don't know why it's not the case